customize subRows in Material React Table
I am using Material React Table to make data table,
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "customerID": "K2176-00011",
    "jobNumber": "SO02005791",
    "workStatus": {
      "SC": "completed",
      "LA": "inprogress",
      "PR": "completed",
      "PA": "inprogress",
      "DS": "waiting",
      "DL": "waiting"
    },
    "date": "04-30-2024",
    "note": "This is notesssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss",
    "updates": true,
    "subRows": [
      {
        "id": 1,

        "jobNumber": "SO02005791",
        "workStatus": {
          "SC": "completed",
          "LA": "completed",
          "PR": "completed",
          "PA": "completed",
          "DS": "completed",
          "DL": "completed"
        }
      
    
    ]
  },

 {
        accessorKey: "date",
        header: "DATE",

        Cell: ({ row }) => (
          <span className={`bg-rose-300 text-rose-950 p-1 rounded-lg`}>
            {row.original.date}
          </span>
        ),

        size: 150,
      },
      {
        accessorKey: "jobNumber",
        header: "Job Number",
        size: 150,
      },
      {
        accessorKey: "customerID",
        header: "Customer ID",
        size: 150,
      },
    
      ...generateColumnsFromWorkStatusKeys(workStatusKeys),
    ];
  }, [fetcheddata]);

  const table = useMaterialReactTable({
    enableColumnActions: false,
    style: {
      width: "50%",
      height: "50%",
      overflow: "auto",
    },
    columns,
    positionExpandColumn: "last",
    data: fetcheddata,
    enableStickyHeader: true,
    enableStickyFooter: true,
    enableExpandAll: true, //hide expand all double arrow in column header
    enableExpanding: true,
    filterFromLeafRows: true, //apply filtering to all rows instead of just parent rows

    initialState: { expanded: false },
    paginateExpandedRows: false, //When rows are expanded, do not count sub-rows as number of rows on the page towards pagination
    layoutMode: "grid-no-grow", //constant column widths
    renderRowActionMenuItems: () => [
      <MenuItem key="action">
        <div className="bg-black w-full h-full">test </div>
      </MenuItem>,
    ],
    enableRowActions: true,
    positionActionsColumn: "last",
    // initialState: {
    //   columnPinning: {
    //     left: ["jobNumber"],
    //   },
    // },
  });

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        maxWidthwidth: "90%",
        marginTop: "50px",
        margin: "0 auto",
        height: "50%",
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}
    >
      <MaterialReactTable table={table} />
    </div>
  );
};

enter image description here
"The 'note' is the main data, and it exists only once. However, I want the 'note' to only appear in the subRows. How can I customize the subRows so that I dont need to include the 'note' in the header but it is displayed on subRows without header,

You can display your note as a part of a neighbouring column, e.g. your DL column. This solution will render it in all of your sub rows. You can play with various table/row/cell props and control that too.
const DLColumn = {
  Cell: ({ row }) => (
    <div>
      // render your LED indicator here, then add additional content
      <span>
        {row.parentId ? row.getParentRow().original.note : ''}
      </span>
    </div>
  ),

